# How to disable ARM coprocessor instructions with gcc?

Tags: gcc, arm, bare-metal

Is there a way with a recent gcc to disable the use of coprocessor instructions: CDP, LDC, STC, MCR and MRC ?

They seem to be grouped in an autoconf variable named arm_coproc1_ok.

I tried to set the options **-march=armv4** and **-mfloat-abi=soft** but nothing helps. My binaries always contain the instructions.

Whether it's my source code or libc (newlib), I find copro instructions.

This c++ code source,

```
double Bbp::S(int j)
{
    double s = 0.0;        // Summation of Total, Left
    double t;              // Each term of right summation
    int    r;              // Denominator
    int    k;              // Loop index
    double EPS = 1.0e-17;  // Loop-exit accuration of the right summation

    // Left Sum (0 ... d)
    for (k = 0; k <= d; k++) {
        r = 8 * k + j;
        t = (double)compModExp(16, d - k, r);
        t /= r;
        s += t - (int)t;
        s -= (int)s;
    }

    // Right sum (d + 1 ...)
    while (1) {
        r = 8 * k + j;
        t = std::pow(16.0, (double)(d - k));
        t /= (double)r;
        if (t < EPS) break;
        s += t;
        s -= (int)s;
        k ++;
    }

    return s;
}
```

...generate this binary (stc at 0x44c):

```
000001c0 <_ZN3Bbp1SEi>:
 1c0:   e52de004        push    {lr}            ; (str lr, [sp, #-4]!)
 1c4:   e24dd034        sub     sp, sp, #52     ; 0x34
 1c8:   e58d0004        str     r0, [sp, #4]
 1cc:   e58d1000        str     r1, [sp]
 1d0:   e3a02000        mov     r2, #0
...
 440:   e49df004        pop     {pc}            ; (ldr pc, [sp], #4)
 444:   e1a00000        nop                     ; (mov r0, r0)
 448:   4646d497                        ; <UNDEFINED> instruction: 0x4646d497
 44c:   3c670ef5        stclcc  14, cr0, [r7], #-980    ; 0xfffffc2c
```

Same remark with libc.a of newlib at 0x080 (mrc instruction):

```
00000028 <etens>:
  28:   4a926576        bmi     fe499608 <enan+0xfe49565c>
  2c:   153f804a        ldrne   r8, [pc, #-74]! ; ffffffea <enan+0xffffc03e>
  30:   979ac94c        ldrls   ip, [sl, ip, asr #18]
...
  5c:   75868175        strvc   r8, [r6, #373]  ; 0x175
  60:   4d48c976        vstrmi.16       s25, [r8, #-236]        ; 0xffffff14    ; <UNPREDICTABLE>
  64:   58f89c66        ldmpl   r8!, {r1, r2, r5, r6, sl, fp, ip, pc}^
  68:   5c54bc50        mrrcpl  12, 5, fp, r4, cr0
  6c:   91c6cc65        bicls   ip, r6, r5, ror #24
  70:   a0aea60e        adcge   sl, lr, lr, lsl #12
  74:   46a3e319        ssatmi  lr, #4, r9, lsl #6
  78:   eab7851e        b       fede14f8 <enan+0xfeddd54c>
  7c:   901b98fe                        ; <UNDEFINED> instruction: 0x901b98fe
  80:   de8dddbb        mcrle   13, 4, sp, cr13, cr11, {5}
```

...among others obviouly.

Thank you.

Comment: meaning when you write assembly language code for these instructions the tools still assemble them?  or the libraries you choose to link with the project happen to have these indepedent of your code that you built with those limits?

Comment: explain for example how you are getting mrc/mcr with gcc compiled C code.  please provide a minimal example.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I amend my question.

Comment: that is not an stc instruction in the first one that is the disassembler disassembling data.  same goes for the mcr in the second one.  just some pool data.

Comment: in order to change those you need to change the data values in the program such that they dont resemble those instructions.

Answer (score 1):

```
double fun ( void )
{
    double EPS = 1.0e-17;
    return(EPS);
}

00000000 <fun>:
   0:   e28f1008    add r1, pc, #8
   4:   e8910003    ldm r1, {r0, r1}
   8:   e1a0f00e    mov pc, lr
   c:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
  10:   4646d497            ; <UNDEFINED> instruction: 0x4646d497
  14:   3c670ef5    stclcc  14, cr0, [r7], #-980    ; 0xfffffc2c
```

of which

code:

```
00000000 <fun>:
   0:   e28f1008    add r1, pc, #8
   4:   e8910003    ldm r1, {r0, r1}
   8:   e1a0f00e    mov pc, lr
```

padding?

```
   c:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
```

data pool:

```
  10:   4646d497            ; <UNDEFINED> instruction: 0x4646d497
  14:   3c670ef5    stclcc  14, cr0, [r7], #-980    ; 0xfffffc2c
```

and here you go

```
double fun ( void )
{
    double EPS = 1.0e-16;
    return(EPS);
}

00000000 <fun>:
   0:   e28f1008    add r1, pc, #8
   4:   e8910003    ldm r1, {r0, r1}
   8:   e1a0f00e    mov pc, lr
   c:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
  10:   97d889bc            ; <UNDEFINED> instruction: 0x97d889bc
  14:   3c9cd2b2    lfmcc   f5, 1, [r12], {178} ; 0xb2
```

the correct way to view the disassembled information is:

```
00000000 <fun>:
   0:   e28f1008    add r1, pc, #8
   4:   e8910003    ldm r1, {r0, r1}
   8:   e1a0f00e    mov pc, lr
   c:   e1a00000
  10:   4646d497
  14:   3c670ef5
```

another way to look at this is to compile to asm

```
    .arch armv4
    .eabi_attribute 20, 1
    .eabi_attribute 21, 1
    .eabi_attribute 23, 3
    .eabi_attribute 24, 1
    .eabi_attribute 25, 1
    .eabi_attribute 26, 1
    .eabi_attribute 30, 2
    .eabi_attribute 34, 0
    .eabi_attribute 18, 4
    .file   "so.c"
    .text
    .align  2
    .global fun
    .syntax unified
    .arm
    .fpu softvfp
    .type   fun, %function
fun:
    @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 0
    @ frame_needed = 0, uses_anonymous_args = 0
    @ link register save eliminated.
    adr r1, .L3
    ldmia   r1, {r0-r1}
    mov pc, lr
.L4:
    .align  3
.L3:
    .word   1179047063
    .word   1013386997
    .size   fun, .-fun
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 9.2.0"
```

notice the lack of an stc instructions?  If you convert those .words to hex you will see the pattern that a disassembler would recognize as an stc if it didnt know this was data.

And we can see where the nop came from.

Comment: How do we say ""j'ai honte" in english ? I am ashamed ?
A big thank you ! Thanks to you, I understood.

Comment: you are not the first and not the last.  disassemblers can only do so much, the are not and cannot be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You’re reading the literal pool (data) as code. Those “instructions” will never execute.

Try turning your

```
double EPS = 1.0e-17;  // Loop-exit accuration of the right summation
```

Constant in to hexadecimal, and you’ll see why no amount of GCC options will eliminate this from your generated binary!

Comment: Thank you James ! I understood now.